# VBA for Duplicates (specific need)

Tags: excel, vba

I've been scouring stackoverflow and haven't found what I am looking for. Which is frustrating because I know I can't be the only one who has come across this.

I have an excel spreadsheet with 26k rows -- and I need to purge all rows where column D and E have same values -- except I want to keep at most 10 rows and purge rest. In some instances there will only be 3 duplicate rows so those can stay.

Here is example of my spreadsheet.

```
+------+-------+--------+---------+---------+
| Code | Local | Number | Place A | Place B |
+------+-------+--------+---------+---------+
| A    | 558   | 25     | DEW     | ABE     |
+------+-------+--------+---------+---------+
| A    | 485   | 14     | DEW     | FXD     |
+------+-------+--------+---------+---------+
| A    | 658   | 85     | DEW     | ABE     |
+------+-------+--------+---------+---------+
| A    | 225   | 68     | ABE     | FXD     |
+------+-------+--------+---------+---------+
| A    | 1     | 56     | ABE     | FXD     |
+------+-------+--------+---------+---------+
| A    | 47    | 412    | DEW     | CDE     |
+------+-------+--------+---------+---------+
```

Imagine I had 15 rows where Place A and Place B were DEW and ABE -- I would want to delete 5 of those. I don't care what 5, just 5 have to go and I need to be left with 10.

Comment: In F2 put  `=COUNTIFS(D$2:D2,D2,E$2:E2,E2)>10` and fill down.  Copy/paste values in Col F then delete all rows where colF = TRUE

Comment: THANK YOU! This worked like champ. I was able to cut down my record from 26k to 15k.

Answer (score 0):

Tim Williams' comment will do exactly what you're after and is far simpler than a VBA solution:

```
Public Sub FilterRange(ByRef TargetTable As Range, ByVal TargetColumns As Variant, Optional ByVal MaxDuplicateCount As Long = 10, _
  Optional ByVal IsCaseSensitive As Boolean = False, Optional ByVal Delimiter As String = "^&")

  Dim Temp As Variant, x As Long, y As Long

  'Error checking
  If Not IsArray(TargetColumns) Then
    MsgBox "Target columns must be provided as a one dimensional array i.e. ""Array(1, 4, 5)"" ", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
  End If

  'More error checking
  For x = 0 To UBound(TargetColumns, 1)
    If Not IsNumeric(TargetColumns(x)) Then
      MsgBox "Invalid column number supplied: " & TargetColumns(x), vbCritical
      Exit Sub
    ElseIf TargetColumns(x) < 1 Then
      MsgBox "Invalid column number supplied: " & TargetColumns(x), vbCritical
      Exit Sub
    ElseIf TargetColumns(x) > TargetTable.Columns.Count Then
      MsgBox "Invalid column number supplied: " & TargetColumns(x), vbCritical
      Exit Sub
    End If
  Next x

  'Create Dictionary object
  Dim DuplicateCounter As Object, ThisRowVal As Variant
  Set DuplicateCounter = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

  'Set Dictionary case sensitivity
  If IsCaseSensitive Then
    DuplicateCounter.CompareMode = 0
  Else
    DuplicateCounter.CompareMode = 1
  End If

  'Pull table into an array
  Temp = TargetTable.Value

  'Check each row in the array
  For x = 1 To UBound(Temp, 1)

    'Determine this row's unique value (based on the supplied columns)
    ThisRowVal = Empty
    For y = 0 To UBound(TargetColumns, 1)
      ThisRowVal = ThisRowVal & Temp(x, TargetColumns(y)) & Delimiter
    Next y

    'Check for duplicates
    If DuplicateCounter.Exists(ThisRowVal) Then
      If DuplicateCounter(ThisRowVal) >= MaxDuplicateCount Then
        'Too many with this unique value, delete the excess row data
        For y = 1 To UBound(Temp, 2)
          Temp(x, y) = Empty
        Next y
      Else
        'We haven't exceeded the max row count: increment the counter
        DuplicateCounter(ThisRowVal) = DuplicateCounter(ThisRowVal) + 1
      End If
    Else
      'This value is new: add to dictionary with a count of 1
      DuplicateCounter.Add ThisRowVal, 1
    End If

  Next x

  'Write the output data to the table range
  TargetTable.Value = Temp

End Sub
```

If you put the above code into a module, you can write the below into a command button, or type it into the Immediate window.

```
FilterRange Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:E26000"), Array(4, 5)
```

As this pulls the data into an array, it will operate quickly, but will overwrite the table range with values (formulas will be lost). I've written some self-describing optional parameters that allow you to change the code's behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the module -- you were right as Tim's quick filter worked great.